# How to build Stacked graphs in Excel not amounting to 100%

Tags: excel, graph

If I have a data :

```
year    Total Balance   subset 1    subset 2
1                 100         50        20
2                 300        200       175
3                 200         65        35
4                  50         25         5
```

Can i have a stacked column graph with "year" on X-Axis and the Y-Axis should be the balances- maximum being Total Balance and subset 1 and subset 2 be stacked within the Total Balance?

Answer (score 0):

No direct way, however by transforming your values you can do it:

- insert new columns with formula: `=C2*$B2/SUM($C2:$D2)`
- insert your chart based on the new columns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming I got right what you need: insert the graph manually, and select your year values on the axis labels box (right side) and add each column (Total Balance, subset 1, subset 2) individually on the left side box.

[Here's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMh1L.png)

[And here's my 'Select data' windows (sorry it's in portuguese)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJtzf.png)